# Reporting corrected correlations

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

I need to report a large set of correlations whose p values I have already corrected for multiple comparisons using R. I assume that the correlation coefficient will remain the same, as nothing in the r formula has anything to do with how the p value is calculated. 1) Is that correct? 2) And will the r coefficient (which in some cases is quite high) look okay next to a largely non-significant p value?

Any feedback would be appreciated!

Thanks!
S.

Comment: Have you considered reporting each correlation along with a standard error of estimate for each one?  That is more useful than giving p-values and will accomplish your goal of indicating the level of uncertainty or imprecision in each estimate.

Comment: I'll look into that too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, report the $r$ values as they are. Correcting $p$-values is irrelevant.

If you have a small sample even a very large $r$ value can have a $p$-value which falls below some arbitrary level of statistical significance. And vice versa, of course.

Comment: Thank you so much!